# How to externalize log4j.properties in a SpringBoot application

Tags: logging, spring-boot, config

I've a got little Rest API written with spring boot. I deploy it as a war file to a separate Tomcat container. In the `application.properties` file I've specified the logging configuration file like this:

`logging.config = {catalina.home}/conf/castle/log4j.properties`

But I get "No appenders found for logger.." warning. I tried giving absolute path like this

`logging.config = D:/Program Files/Apache Tomcat8/conf/castle/log4j.properties`

to no avail. Only if I put the `log4j.properties` file into the classpath does the warning go away and the logging functions properly. I suspect I have to manually configure this in the code instead of specifying the config path in the `application.properties` file. Is that the case, or is there something simpler?